# onBackPressed() but Activity finished(), then onCreate(), onResume(). Cannot exit app

Tags: android

Android 2.3.6
 Steps to reproduce.
 Goto activity.
 Restart Phone.
 Click Back Button.
 Nothing happens. Actually activity recreated again, then resume called() so cannot exit app.  It just stays on.
 What could cause this. I have selected the app as default app launcher, so maybe this has something to do with it.

Question is how can this possibly not close the activity? I'm doing on back pressed, and I'm also doing a finish().  I have log statements in onResume(), so I don't think its being restarted. What is it about restarting the phone that does this. It works otherwise.

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();


    }
}
```

UPDATE:  What happens is the activity is immediately recreated. onCreate(), onResume(). So the activity is stopped, but for some reason it does not leave. Here is activity intent filters  in manifest:

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Is there something about this that keeps me from exiting the app?

Comment: can you please send me your activity code . Because as per your issue related to back press it can be solve by code which i have sent you as in answer

Comment: I have updated.  So it does close activity. I see onPause() but then recreates. I see onCreate(), onResume(). The question is why does it recreate it. Why not just take me back to apps screen?

Comment: can u please send code snippets . i didnt get your question , Why you need to write intent filter ?

Comment: My question is why is the activity recreated?  What can cause this? Why not just exit app?

Comment: happens on restart of device. Activity is removed but gets restarted again.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code , hope it helps you.

```
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(Youractivity.this);
finish();
```

Comment: Please explain why this is necessary.  I don't see any reason why the activity gets recreated?  I have updated with my manifest. I did select the app as default. So maybe this means it gets restarted?  I don't know. Why usually after os restart?

Comment: The above code will dismiss or finish youracitvity which in stack.

Comment: It did not work. The problem is the activity gets recreated(), and started(). This happens after restart of device.

Comment: every time click back see onCreate(), onresume() before I get to onStop().

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code hope it will work for you

```
/**
     * This method is use to handle back key event
     */
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: This might work, but I still want to know why my activity get recreated. It does stop the activity. I see onPause().  It then recreates I see onCreate(), onResume(). The question is why? Why would activity get recreated after onBackPressed(), and finish().